# Restrictions of multiple links per model

Tags: gazebo, sdformat, collision, sdf

If i have a model with two links, one containing a visual and the other containing the collider, the colliders won't be considered, and it will fall through everything.

Modified model from the shapes.sdf exmaple

```xml
<model name="box">
    <pose>0 0 0.5 0 0 0</pose>
    <link name="box_link">
        <inertial>
            <inertia>
                <ixx>0.16666</ixx>
                <ixy>0</ixy>
                <ixz>0</ixz>
                <iyy>0.16666</iyy>
                <iyz>0</iyz>
                <izz>0.16666</izz>
            </inertia>
            <mass>1.0</mass>
        </inertial>
        <collision name="box_collision">
            <geometry>
                <box>
                    <size>1 1 1</size>
                </box>
            </geometry>
        </collision>
    </link>
    <link name="box_link2">
        <visual name="box_visual">
            <geometry>
                <box>
                    <size>1 1 1</size>
                </box>
            </geometry>
            <material>
                <ambient>1 0 0 1</ambient>
                <diffuse>1 0 0 1</diffuse>
                <specular>1 0 0 1</specular>
            </material>
        </visual>
    </link>
</model>
```

If i add a collider to the link with the visual, that will work, but the collider in the other link still won't be considered.

The documentation says

> A link must be a child of a model, and any number of links may exist in a model.

Are there other rules to using multiple links?
I'm working on procedurally generating SDFs for Gazebo, so i'm trying to understand these edge cases to make it more reliable.

Using Gazebo Harmonic

Answer (score 0):

I realized what i got wrong. All the links inside a model are separate entities, and i can add joints to connect them. Should have been obvious.